# Why do we need ampleness in the definition of semistability of a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, sheaf-theory

This is a general question that I have. Let $X$ be a projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $L$ be an ample line bundle over $X$. Let $F$ be a vector bundle on $X$. We say that $F$ is $L$-semistable if for any coherent subsheaf $0\neq E\subset F$ of strictly lesser rank, $\mu_L(E)\leq\mu_L(F)$. Here $\mu_L(F)=\frac{c_1(F).L^{n-1}}{r}$, where $r=$ rank$(F)$ and $n=dim\ X$.

My question is, why do we need $L$ to be ample? The definitions and basic properties seem to go through without ampleness. Even the fact that semistability is an open condition does not seem to depend on the fact that $L$ is ample.